# Complicated limit calculation : what approach should be used.

Tags: limits, continuity

what is the approach to this limit calculation:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{3n}+2^{2n+2}}{8^{n+1}+5^{n+100}}$$

Thanks for the support!

Comment: Write each term as $Ab^n$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing *complex* in the title to **complicated**, since *complex* suggests Complex Analysis, which is not intended by the problem.  Then, the interface forced me to append something to prevent a duplication of question titles.

Comment: Factor the dominant term in numerator and in denominator, and show it by editing your post!

Comment: $1/8{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Gon I have tried the approach that Andrei mentioned, but stayed at the same position. markvs points for the answer, which is correct by Wolfram Alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big realization that @zwim points out in the comments is that the terms in the denominator and numerator that aren't the fastest growing don't factor into the final limit. In particular, $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{3n}+2^{2n+2}}{8^{n+1}+5^{n+100}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{3n}}{8^{n+1}}$$Proving that this is true is a great exercise and one that I highly encourage. But once we have this result, the rest is trivial since $2^{3n}=8^n$, so $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{3n}}{8^{n+1}}=\frac18$$

Comment: I learned a lot from your answer. Thank you very much for your dedicated time!